# What are the best select all / deselect all icons

Tags: user-behavior, icons, user-expectation, ease-of-use

I tried google image search, and i see that there are many different icons for this, some are more or less customized based on the context they are in.

In your experience, which icon is most likely to be understood without visible label?

As for the context of my particular problem, I'm trying to select/deselect all items on d3 scatter plot, but please don't let this affect your decision too much, I'm interested in general usage too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for general answers I recommend using a label until and unless you have strict reasons not to use so.

From http://goodui.org/

> Icons can be wide open to interpretation and combining them with words
>   can remove some of the ambiguity. Take a down arrow icon for example.
>   Does it mean to move something down, lower its priority, or download?
>   Or does an “x” icon mean to delete, disable, or close? The problem
>   becomes larger for light use interfaces where there isn’t much time
>   for the person to learn the meaning of the icons. To make the icons
>   more understandable, they can be augmented with textual labels. If
>   space is truly an issue, some user interfaces compromise by showing
>   all of their icon labels on a single hover (less painful than having
>   to hover on each individual icon).

Don't confuse the user , stick to the basics - that is the best way to do your UX. Because users are used to conventions in web , innovations are good as long as they are not hindering with the usability of the website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table, the most logical and widely used "Select All" is a checkbox above the first row's checkbox. Clicking it both selects all and deselects all.

Using this logic, if there is a table associated with your chart, you could have the controls in the table.

Alternatively, you could have the "Remove all" control as part of your graph controls. I'm assuming you have other graph controls (like date ranges, data types etc). You could add this as an additional option. That way you are grouping together similar actions that a user can perform in a single context.